# Github actions specify package name

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions, docker-registry

TL;DR:
I want to know how to publish specific package names to ghcr instead of the repostiry name. How can I do that?

For example:

- docker-php-stack/php74:latest
- docker-php-stack/php80:latest
- docker-php-stack/php81:latest

Instead of what it is now:

- docker-php-stack:sha256-a417bb4fbb9e606fb39012ff6e71219597c5eee8947eef5d99395f880f05368d.sig

*Long version:*

So I am running different actions for different directories with the following action:
(source: https://github.com/bruvv/docker-php-stack)

```
name: Docker-PHP80

# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "20 11 * * *"
  push:
    branches: [main]
    paths:
      - "php80/Dockerfile"
    # Publish semver tags as releases.
    tags: ["v*.*.*"]

env:
  # Use docker.io for Docker Hub if empty
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  # github.repository as <account>/<repo>
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
      # This is used to complete the identity challenge
      # with sigstore/fulcio when running outside of PRs.
      id-token: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Install the cosign tool except on PR
      # https://github.com/sigstore/cosign-installer
      - name: Install cosign
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: sigstore/cosign-installer@9f7b96f21107c0c5f4baf9536853b2554b4179f7
        with:
          cosign-release: "v1.4.0"

      # Workaround: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/461
      - name: Setup Docker buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@2a6fbda6d8bd6fe40f8b36c71fca20ffc286129e

      # Login against a Docker registry except on PR
      # https://github.com/docker/login-action
      - name: Log into registry ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@7c79b598eaa33458e78e8d0d71e0a9c217dd92af
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      # https://github.com/docker/metadata-action
      - name: Extract Docker metadata
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@1237c3e3d6926ae8bfad16f64e08d259b9943637
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

      # Build and push Docker image with Buildx (don't push on PR)
      # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        id: build-and-push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@f7a2a67b4c1059633be6daa491784d8ac6a7ed6d
        with:
          context: ./php80
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}

      # Sign the resulting Docker image digest except on PRs.
      # This will only write to the public Rekor transparency log when the Docker
      # repository is public to avoid leaking data.  If you would like to publish
      # transparency data even for private images, pass --force to cosign below.
      # https://github.com/sigstore/cosign
      - name: Sign the published Docker image
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        env:
          COSIGN_EXPERIMENTAL: "true"
        # This step uses the identity token to provision an ephemeral certificate
        # against the sigstore community Fulcio instance.
        run: cosign sign ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}@${{ steps.build-and-push.outputs.digest }}
```

What I want is:

- docker-php-stack/php74:latest
- docker-php-stack/php80:latest
- docker-php-stack/php81:latest

instead of what it is now: https://github.com/bruvv/docker-php-stack/pkgs/container/docker-php-stack

I tried changing the following:

```
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
```

But I am getting:

```
error: failed to solve: unexpected status: 400 Bad Request
Error: buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: unexpected status: 400 Bad Request
```

That is all I was able to find online. So far I am out of ideas.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and how that did not work.

Comment: Here are some tips on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask There's also a link on how to create a minimal sample that reproduces your problem rather than just pasting all the YAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it when the following to docker/metadata-action

```
          tags: |
            type=raw,value=somethingyouwant-latest
```

```
name: Docker-PHP74

# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

on:
#   schedule:
#     - cron: "20 11 * * *"
  push:
    branches: [main]
    paths:
      - "php74/Dockerfile"
    # Publish semver tags as releases.
    tags: ["v*.*.*"]

env:
  # Use docker.io for Docker Hub if empty
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  # github.repository as <account>/<repo>
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
      # This is used to complete the identity challenge
      # with sigstore/fulcio when running outside of PRs.
      id-token: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Install the cosign tool except on PR
      # https://github.com/sigstore/cosign-installer
      - name: Install cosign
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: sigstore/cosign-installer@v2.1.0

      # Workaround: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/461
      - name: Setup Docker buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1.6.0

      # Login against a Docker registry except on PR
      # https://github.com/docker/login-action
      - name: Log into registry ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@v1.14.1
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      # https://github.com/docker/metadata-action
      - name: Extract Docker metadata
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v3.6.2
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
          #flavor: prefix=php74 #this becomes php74main
          tags: |
            type=raw,value=php74-latest
          

      # Build and push Docker image with Buildx (don't push on PR)
      # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        id: build-and-push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2.10.0
        with:
          context: ./php74
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}

      # Sign the resulting Docker image digest except on PRs.
      # This will only write to the public Rekor transparency log when the Docker
      # repository is public to avoid leaking data.  If you would like to publish
      # transparency data even for private images, pass --force to cosign below.
      # https://github.com/sigstore/cosign
      - name: Sign the published Docker image
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        env:
          COSIGN_EXPERIMENTAL: "true"
        # This step uses the identity token to provision an ephemeral certificate
        # against the sigstore community Fulcio instance.
        run: cosign sign ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}@${{ steps.build-and-push.outputs.digest }}
```

Comment: If this worked for you, then you could accept your own answer